# I need to decrypt the JWE response in java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, jwt, jwe

I'm able to get the decrypted data(payload) but not able to verify that the data is not changed in the transmission.

the Encrypted Key is decrypted using your RSA private key with the "alg" algorithm specified in the Header to produce the symmetric key. Next, the JWE decryption library is used to decrypt the Cipher Text using the symmetric key, Initialization Vector, Tag and ascii-encoded Header, with the "enc" algorithm in the Header.

**JavaScript working code**

```js
// Decrypt JWE using private key
security.decryptJWE = function decryptJWE(header, encryptedKey, iv, cipherText, tag, privateKey) {
  console.log("Decrypting JWE".green + " (Format: " + "header".red + "." + "encryptedKey".cyan + "." + "iv".green + "." + "cipherText".magenta + "." + "tag".yellow + ")");
  console.log(header.red + "." + encryptedKey.cyan + "." + iv.green + "." + cipherText.magenta + "." + tag.yellow);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var keystore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore();

    console.log((new Buffer(header,'base64')).toString('ascii'));

    var data = {
      "type": "compact",
      "ciphertext": cipherText,
      "protected": header,
      "encrypted_key": encryptedKey,
      "tag": tag,
      "iv": iv,
      "header": JSON.parse(jose.util.base64url.decode(header).toString())
    };
    keystore.add(fs.readFileSync(privateKey, 'utf8'), "pem")
      .then(function(jweKey) {
        // {result} is a jose.JWK.Key
        jose.JWE.createDecrypt(jweKey)
          .decrypt(data)
          .then(function(result) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(result.payload.toString()));
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            reject(error);
          });
      });

  })
  .catch (error => {
    console.error("Error with decrypting JWE: %s".red, error);
    throw "Error with decrypting JWE";
  })
}
```

The following Java code is missing the verification part because I don't know how to do it.

**Java code**

```java
private String decryptJWT(String token) {
    JWEObject jweObject;
    try {
        jweObject = JWEObject.parse(token);
        // Decrypt with shared key
        byte[] b1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(PRIVATE_KEY);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(kf.generatePrivate(spec));
        jweObject.decrypt(decrypter);
        // Extract payload
        SignedJWT signedJWT = jweObject.getPayload().toSignedJWT();
        return signedJWT.getPayload().toJSONObject().toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

/*I have tried this code to verify but it's not working.*/
RSAKey serverPublicKey = RSAKey.parse(signedJWT.getHeader().getJWK().toJSONObject());
if (signedJWT.verify(new RSASSAVerifier(serverPublicKey))) {
    return signedJWT.getPayload().toJSONObject().toString();
}
```

Comment: Take a look to this gist, https://gist.github.com/salgmachine/352799a6052b02901982dcbf85d30346#file-oauth2authorizationserverconfigjwt-java-L121-L184